# Bootstrap - Panel group - unjustified spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have this issue with the Boostrap panel group, the basic html below:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

<div class="panel panel-default">

<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">Create a task</a>
</h4>
</div>

<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">

<div class="panel-body">

</div><!-- /panel-body -->
</div><!-- /panel-collapse -->
</div><!-- /panel-default -->

</div><!-- /panel-group -->
```

I wanted to add a title above this panel group so I added the code below:

```
<h4 class="title-custom">Active tasks<h4>
```

I have cancelled out all the margin that is added to a `h4` tag by bootstrap, so I was expecting the header to come right above the panel-group, but for some reason there's a space between that I don't know where it's coming from. I tried the Developer tools within two browsers, but the spacing is not even detected. I really don't know where it's coming from and I thought someone here might know.

Thank you.

Comment: We are not here to read your code. Setup a demo at jsfiddle or codepen or whatever

Comment: @knitevision...we kind of are...but a working example is always welcome :)

Comment: Have you removed the margin from the h4 inside the panel-group?

Comment: Realised I had a css rule for it :/ Shoot me now.

Comment: So that was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<h4 class="title-custom">Active tasks<h4>` use `<h4 class="title-custom">Active tasks</h4>`.

That is, close the `h4` tag. Right now it inserts a new heading.

[Demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GfbyIuEhFhRD7iQjb4Bz?p=preview)